# API Como passar resultado de uma função js para arquivo de rotas

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, api, http

Sou iniciante e comecei a estudar sobre a criação de APIs com nodeJs, pegando algumas documentações consegui implementar algumas funcionalidades, tenho uma função de buscar que traz o resultado da pesquisa como result. ao imprimir no console dentro da propria função, consigo retornar o resultado da pesquisa em json, mas ao dar um return nessa função e chama-la no meu arquivo de rotas atribuindo-a a uma variável ela vem como undefined, alguém poderia me ajudar com esse problema?

ps: quero passar o resultado para o arquivo de rotas para fazer um response com o resultado

segue o codigo do meu arquivo de funcionalidades

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const routes = require('./routes')

var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var url = "mongodb://localhost:27017/mydb";

///inserir dados
exports.Inserir = function(myobj){
    MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
        if (err) throw err;
        var dbo = db.db("mydb");
        dbo.collection("customers").insertOne(myobj, function(err, res) {
        if (err) throw err;
        db.close();
        });
    });
}

//buscar dados
exports.Buscar = function(query){
  var resultado = MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
    if (err) throw err;
    var dbo = db.db("mydb");
    dbo.collection("customers").find(query).toArray(function(err, result) {
      if (err) throw err;
      return result
      db.close();
    });
  });
}

//deletar dados
exports.Deletar = function(myquery){
  MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
    if (err) throw err;
    var dbo = db.db("mydb");
    dbo.collection("customers").deleteMany(myquery, function(err, obj) {
      if (err) throw err;
      console.log("1 document deleted");
      db.close();
    });
  });
}

exports.Atualizar = function(){
MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
  if (err) throw err;
  var dbo = db.db("mydb");
  var myquery = { address: "Mountain 21" };
  var newvalues = { $set: {name: "Mickey", address: "Canyon 123" } };
  dbo.collection("customers").updateMany(myquery, newvalues, function(err, res) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log("1 document updated");
    db.close();
  });
});
}
```

meu arquivo de rotas

```
const Connection = require('mysql/lib/Connection')
const routes = express.Router()
const connnection = require('./conection')


module.exports = routes
 

//Busca Dados
routes.get('/busca', (req, res) =>{
  resultado = connnection.Buscar( { address: "Mountain 22" })
  console.log(resultado)
  res.end();
})

//Inserir Dados
routes.post('/add', (req,res) => {
        dados = req.body
        connnection.Inserir(dados);
        res.write('Cadastrado com sucesso')
        res.end();
})

//Deleta Dados
routes.delete('/delete', (req, res) =>{
    dados = req.body
    connnection.Deletar(dados);
    res.end();
})

//Atualizar dados
routes.patch('/edit', (req, res) =>{
    connnection.Atualizar();
    res.end();
})
```

Comment: No teu helper de "Buscar" vc não está fazendo o retorno da variável, por isso lá no teu routes está vindo como undefined, basta você retornar o resultado `return MongoClient.connect(....`.

Answer (score 0):

Fala Rafael, blza?

Você está importando o express mas praticamente vc não está fazendo uso dele. No teu segundo arquivo importe o express completo, não somente o routes.

Como sugestão, utilize uma constante para facilitar. Vc precisa tbm ser explicito em qual formato vc quer que o expressa faça o cast.

```
const app = express();
app.use(express.json());
```

Outra coisa que pode ser feita é vc dar logo o feedback no teu res, facilita

```
//Busca Dados
app.get('/busca', (req, res) =>{
  resultado = connnection.Buscar( { address: "Mountain 22" })
  console.log(resultado)
  res.status(200).json(resultado);
})
```